# cannot show the field 'name' in REST API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I try to retrieve all data from my REST API I get them correctly except from one field, that is the field 'name' from Skill class. Instead of the 'name' I get only its id. Can you help me to resolve this?----------------------------------------------

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj4rH.png)
Here is the code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ImageField
from django.utils.text import slugify



class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    front_page = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="broken-image.png")
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    
        if self.slug == None:
            slug = slugify(self.title)

            has_slug = Project.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
            count = 1
            while has_slug:
                count += 1
                slug = slugify(self.title) + '-' + str(count) 
                has_slug = Project.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()

            self.slug = slug

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from project.models import Project, Skill


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from project.models import Project, Skill
from .serializers import ProjectSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@api_view(['GET'])
def getData(request):
    project = Project.objects.all()
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
    serializer= ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def update(request, pk):
    item = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serializer = ProjectSerializer(instance=item, data=request.data)
  
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)



@api_view(['DELETE'])
def delete(request, pk):
    item = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    item.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getData),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', views.update),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', views.delete),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to specify that you want to use the `name` of the skills, so:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from project.models import Project, Skill


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    skills = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True, slug_field='name', queryset=Skill.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

The nice thing of such `SlugRelatedField` is that this can work *bidrectional*: not only can you serialize data, but you can also use it to specify skills and thus create or update `Project`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `SkillSerializer` and refer to it in your `ProjectSerializer`. Also, it is better to specify the fields you want in your serializers explicitly, as `__all__` may expose the fields you don't want to expose or cause unwanted database queries.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships